# Interpreting the formula for Riemannian metric tensor

Tags: feature-selection, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

In [Improving support vector machine classifiers by modifying kernel functions](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12662656/), the authors defined Riemannian metric tensor for a kernel as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
g(\vec{x}) &= \text{det}|g_{ij}(\vec{x})| 
\nonumber\\
g_{ij}(\vec{x}) 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} K\left(\vec{x}, \vec{x'}\right) |_{\vec{x'} = \vec{x}}
\nonumber\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \phi(\vec{x})\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \phi(\vec{x})\right)   
\end{align}
$$

How should I interpret ${\vec{x'} = \vec{x}}$? Here, $K$ is a kernel function and $\phi$ is a feature map.

Comment: "How ... interpret" is a vague question.  What would constitute an interpretation?  Telling you it literally means two vectors are equal, component by component?  Or something beyond that?  Please give us some guidance concerning what form of answer you are seeking.

Comment: "Telling you it literally means two vectors are equal, component by component" is what I was suspecting @whuber. What I would like to understand is what happens when the two vectors are not equal. Why did the authors feel the need to specify the equality?

Comment: The metric is a matrix-valued function given by the array of all second-order partial derivatives (the second line).  What is it a function of? As defined, it is not a function of the set of all possible ordered pairs $(x,x^\prime):$ it is really a function of a *single* variable whose domain is the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\}=\{(x,x^\prime)\mid x = x^\prime\}.$ Notice, though, that the partial derivatives require $K$ to be defined and differentiable *in a neighborhood* of $\Delta.$ It would not work to first restrict $K$ to $\Delta$ and then attempt to compute these partials.

Comment: (The notation, though, is abominable.  In particular, the second line does not mean what it says.  Literally it is taking second partial derivatives *only with respect to the first argument of $K$* and, also literally, the third equality is incorrect: but it's the *intended* equality, so we can use it to reverse-engineer the intended meaning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g_{ij}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$, i.e. your left hand side depends only on the $\mathbf{x}$, but $K$ also depends on $\mathbf{x}'$. So what to do? What it probably tells you is:

$$
g_{ij}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'_j}K\left(\mathbf{x},\,\mathbf{x}'\right)\right]_{\mathbf{x}'=\mathbf{x}}
$$

That is you evaluate the derivative with respect to i-th component of the first param, and j-th component of the second param, along the trajectory $\mathbf{x}'=\mathbf{x}$ (where second param is equal to first).

The non-trivial part is that one of the derivatives is for the first param and the other is for the second param.